# Voltage divider with serial resistor connected to BOOT1 pin from STM32F10X microcontroller

Tags: circuit-analysis, stm32, gpio, digital-input, boot-configure

I was viewing a circuit in a schematics that is given to me. I found this voltage divider with a resistor connected to the BOOT1 pin from a microcontroller:

[image: voltage divider with 3 resistors at BOOT1 input pin]

NOTE: BOOT1 is connected to the BOOT1 microcontroller pin. There are no more elements connected this net.

In STM32Fxx families BOOT1 and BOOT0 are a 2-bit port used for boot system. But BOOT1 is only considered when BOOT0 is getting a certain value that means "go and read the BOOT1 pin logic level". Depending on B1 value the system will start instruction reading from a memory zone or another one.
BOOT1 is an input pin, this means this pin is high-impedance in order to read voltage. This needs no current driving through the pin.

Looking at the circuit I can see:

- how the pin is floating, so R29 resistor won't get voltage falling, because there is no current through resistor.
- how the voltage divider is fixing this pin to a half of VCC that is 3.3 V/2 = 1.65 V, because resistor R29 has no influence on the voltage divider.
- Acording to this expression: [image: stm32f10 VIH expression] allowed VIHmin = 1.833V
- Acording to this another one: [image: VIL expression] allowed VILmax = 1.16 V
- It seems to be an indetermined value.

If I'm not wrong, I don't understand why to fix BOOT1 to a half of 3.3 V.

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: The answer will depend on if the schematics are accurate, and if in real world only one of the pull resistors is present.

Comment: I will check if the 3 Rs are soldered. I have the PCB here that is part of a system that is working well for a couple of years. It's the scheme corresponding to an under production circuit.

Comment: Which exact MCU it is? STM32F10XYZ, please fill in X, Y and Z. In any case, if the resistors do set the voltage to 1.65V, it is a design error. If you intend to measure voltage, measure from the divider side of R29, because MCU side of R29 might be an output when firmware is running.

Comment: @Justme I'have just checked this, the three resistors are mounted on the board.

Comment: @Justme it is the STM32F10XVXT6. The 1.65V is acording to my calculation. But this calculation is made from assumptions that I made. It's not the result of any measure, because the card I have is only a unique sample. I share my analyisis asking for missing assumptions. Is it correct that BOOT1 is seeing 1.65V, looking at the scheme?

Comment: STM32F10XVXT6 is not a valid MCU name. Please make sure you give a valid MCU product code.  And yes your calculations are correct but what if the card does not match the schematics, like already said here, but it's you who needs to measure or look at the board if the resistors are there nor not. Is the board supposed to boot into bootloader or SRAM, do you expect the BOOT1 to be high or low at boot?

Comment: @Justme as I said, the three resistors are there. They are mounted and they are connected like scheme. And forgive me, XVX maybe are "generic" digits for scheme symbols used by the CAD tool. The mcu mounted on the card is STM32F103VCT6. I don't know what they expected to be for BOOT1. I should ask the design author for this. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Even if there are three resistors, you cannot be sure if they are the values shown in the schematics, unless you verify it. One of them could be 0R instead if 10k. You need to measure, preferably from the voltage on those resistors, and when the MCU is in reset. Because you can't reliably measure resistor resistances in-circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said at the comments, there are 3 resistors mounted on the PCB, but I was checking the third resistor at the wrong place. Resistor R316 is actually not mounted.

**So pull up configuration doesn't exists on this board version**. Although there is annotation carence on these schematics sheets, I think this scheme has CAD layout updating proposals.

Let me explain it and let me name the Rpull Up connections: option A, and Rpull Down connections: option B.

This way designer lets the chance for two mounting options (A/B) and he also lets the possibility of fixing BOOT1 to HIGH (option A) or fixing BOOT1 to LOW (option B), but not both at the same time. **Only one of them will be finally mounted.** If R316 is mounted, R317 should be removed and Rpull Down configuration is goten for BOOT1 pin. When R316 is mounted, the other one should be removed and Rpull Up will be goten for BOOT1 connection.